# Are there compact Riemannian manifolds whith Q-curvature negative?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Are there known examples of compact Riemannian manifolds with Q-curvature negative?

Comment: It might help if you gave a definition of $Q$-curvature or a reference that defines it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.   Consult [this reference](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~chang/whatisQ.pdf), for example, for the definition of $Q$-curvature.

In dimension $2$, the $Q$-curvature is essentially just the Gauss curvature, so any compact Riemann surface with genus $g>2$ carries a conformal metric with negative Gauss curvature and hence negative $Q$-curvature.

Meanwhile, in dimension $4$,
$$
Q = \left(-\tfrac16\Delta R - \tfrac12 R^{ab}R_{ab} + \tfrac16 R^2\right)\mathrm{d}vol
$$
where $R$ is the scalar curvature and $R_{ab}$ represents the Ricci curvature.  Obviously, any compact manifold with vanishing scalar curvature will have non-positive $Q$, and one can easily construct many examples that have $Q$ strictly negative.  For example, the product of the unit $2$-sphere and a compact Riemann surface with Gauss curvature identically equal to $-1$ will have vanishing scalar curvature, but won't be Einstein, so it will have $Q$ be strictly negative.